# Need suggestion related to handling threads in C++

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winsock

I've a developing a server app which accepts incoming connections from clients and create thread for every client (which connects)

The problem is; I don't know where should I place `WaitForMultipleObjects` so that I can release the resources of those clients (threads) which are disconnected.

Here is the pseudo structure of how I'm doing this. In my main thread, I'm doing the following:

```
For (ClientId = 0; ClientId < NumOfClientsSupported; ClientId++){

Wait_for_Incoming_Connection();     // Continuously listening incoming connection requests of clients

thread_handle_array[ClientId] = CreateThread(...); // Create thread for each client

// Do some other stuff

}
// Outside loop
WaitForMultipleObjects(...); // Would like to join unusable (disconnected clients) threads here
```

Let say, I've 10 clients connected and 1 somehow disconnect (returns to main thread) and now I want to free the resources it has used; for this I've call `WaitForMultipleObjects()` but I cannot leave loop because I'm listening to other clients connections.

Should I use another thread for just WaitForMultipleObjects() ? Or is their are better way of doing this.

Would appreciate any help

Comment: On read three, I think your answer is use a [thread pool.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool) When `WaitForMultipleObjects` says a socket needs to be handled, throw the job at the thread pool. The pool will assign the job to the next idle thread.

Comment: @user4581301 On windows with MSVC using  std::async does just that, use a threadpool. 
So you could start the job sort of like this. #include <future>, auto ft = std::async(std::launch::async, [this]{ job(); }); But be very careful what you capture, it must have a longer lifetime then the thread you start (or extend the lifetime of what's captured) (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async)

Comment: Creating a thread for each connection is a bad idea (usually). One thread should be able to handle thousands of connections simultaneously (for normal things), as network is the slowest part of the connection multiplexing between connections is normal.

Comment: Use [I/O Completion Ports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/i-o-completion-ports).